# error in typeanumber - android.support.v4.app.fragment cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, google-play-games

Im using eclipse ide and recently decided to try out the google play game services. Im following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#before_you_begin

Ive added the google play services SDK by downloading using android SDK manager, then copying the folder to my workspace. I then used file>import>android>project from exisiting code.

In step three it is adking me to import the typeanumber project. However as soon as i import it there are errors in it.

Am i doing something wrong?

Ive searched around but nothing seems to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself by adding the google-play-lib library and BaseGameUtil to the Android build path NOT the java build path. That is, under project properties, in the Android tab, add the libraries

Answer (score 14):

Go to the project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs 
(Under 'extras' folder select 'Android' -> support -> v4 -> android-support-v4.jar)
Add the file and build the project to get rid of this error

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure `android-support-v4.jar` is in your project Libraries (in project properties, under Java Build Path.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

I got that error too, but I used appCompat library. You must close appCompat project then clean your project, run it until it failed. Then open the appCompat project, then clean your project, and run it.

Answer (score 0):

`android.support.v4.app.fragment` cannot be resolved

hay guys find easy way

1-`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

2-here is the code will looks like.

```
if (view == findViewById(R.id.button))
{
    fragment = new FragmentOne();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =getSupportFragmentManager(); 
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction replace = ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment); 
    ft.commit();
}
```

you will just add `android.support.v4.app.getSupportFragmentManager();` instead `getFragmentManager();`

it works good luck.